# Android flutter app internet acces doesn't work

Tags: android, flutter

So basically I'm doing a HTTP GET request to get data from my MariaDB and visualize it via a Line-Chart Diagram, this works like a charm on the IOS simulator. But it won't work on android, no matter what i do.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2rxK.png)
My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wassermanagmentsystem">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <application
        android:label="Wassermanagment"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

I already tried adding the

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

to the xml but it still wont work

Comment: try to add on debug and main src manifest

Comment: Have you tried running it on a real Android phone instead of just the simulator? Some things don't work in the Android simulator.

Comment: already did on all

Comment: just tried it on an android phone still doesn't work

Comment: Try `flutter clean` and retry. If still persists, perhaps can post the dart code and errors coming out from the console for a closer looks.

Comment: You need to enable clear text traffic for http protocol on Android 11+ devices. Add it to application tag in manifest file.

Comment: i tried flutter clean and it still not working the console says /flutter ( 9912): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused, also i added now android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> in my AndroidManifest.xml, nothing changed. And when i tried to deploy the app on my S8 with android 9 it still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out why it was not working its because the AVD doesn't like localhost :facepalm: